# Read JSON File and Change the Content in it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a `movie_data.json` file. I want to read the `json` file and change `99popularity` to `popularity`

```
[
  {
    "99popularity": 83.0,
    "director": "Victor Fleming",
    "genre": [
      "Adventure",
      " Family",
      " Fantasy",
      " Musical"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 8.3,
    "name": "The Wizard of Oz"
  },
  {
    "99popularity": 88.0,
    "director": "George Lucas",
    "genre": [
      "Action",
      " Adventure",
      " Fantasy",
      " Sci-Fi"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 8.8,
    "name": "Star Wars"
  },
]
```

I tried to read the json file

```
import json

with open('movie_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data['director'])
```

It was giving me error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json-read.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(data['director'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `data` is actually a list of dicts, not a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load in the file, and then you can use the `pop` attribute to swap the key:

```py
import json

with open('movie_data.json') as fh:
    file = json.load(fh)

for entry in file:
    try:
        # remove the key with pop and re-set it with the value that pop returns
        entry['popularity'] = entry.pop('99popularity')
    except KeyError as e: # Key isn't found, skip
        continue

with open('new_movie_data.json', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(json.dumps(file, indent=3)) # indent will format your file
```